# Weighted hinge loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I am defining my vanilla hinge loss as:

```
def hinge(y_true, y_pred):    
    return tf.maximum(0., 1- y_true*y_pred)
```

I'm training an SVM to predict an event. And my `y` values are `1` if it's that class or `-1` if it's not that class. My class is imbalanced that I have much more `-1` than `+1`.

Hence, I'd like to weight the loss `+1` to be higher penalty. But I'm not how exactly I'd change my hinge loss. The best I can think of is,

```
X = (# of non event samples) / (# of event samples)
if(y_true*y_pred > 0):
    return tf.maximum(0., 1- y_true*y_pred)*X
```

This means, if I have a 100 non-event and 10 event, then `X` = 100/10 = 10.
The loss is then `hingeloss*10` if `y_true = 1`.

Is this right or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```py
def hinge(y_true, y_pred):    
    return tf.multiply((11/9+y_true)*9/2,tf.maximum(0., 1- y_true*y_pred))
```

The logic here is that we want to multiply by 10 if `y_true` is 1,  and by 1 if it is -1 . You can check that when `y_true` is -1, `(11/9+y_true)*9/2` evaluates to 1, and when it is 1, it evaluates to 10. If you are interested in knowing how to derive the 11/9 in the expession, it is the result of solving the linear equation for the desired shift s:

10(s + (-1))=1(s+1).

Comment: Hmm, interesting thought. But this is suggesting I know that I want to multiply by 10. I'm interested in how to get the 10 in the first place. I got 10 by just inversely weighting the two classes. But if the class imbalance was 1000 and 10, then your equation becomes 100(s+(-1)) =s+1. And, so the coefficient on the left is what I'm really after.

Comment: How to properly choose that coefficient.

Comment: You will probably have a tradeoff between precision and recall, you could try choosing the one that maximizes your F1 score https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score through cross-validation, or Choosing a precision threshold and maximize the recall subject to getting at least that amount of precision.

Comment: You can also just weight them by the inverse proportion of elements in each class like you suggest, although in your example that would be  (100+10)/10=11. I have no idea what precision and recall you will get, but i imagine it will be more balanced.